# How to set axis label in more lines in igx-data-chart?

Tags: ignite-ui-angular

I need to custom my x-axis label so that it show the label in two lines. I've tried this:

```
let labelFormat = new IgxTimeAxisLabelFormatComponent(); 
labelFormat.format = "dd/MM/yyyy" + "\n" + "hh:mm:ss"; 
this.xAxis.labelFormats.add(labelFormat);
```

But the result is that it stays on a single line, like this:

[image: X-Axis On A Single Line].

Have you any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I dont think that is possible simply through the API. The [label format method](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/api/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxtimeaxislabelformatcomponent.html#format) should be used for common formats like 'MM/dd/yy' or the ones that you are using.
BUT, if you want to change the actual appearance of the label then [formatLabel](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/api/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxaxiscomponent.html#formatlabel) should be the path to follow. While creating an example for you, I realized that the returned value is of type string, so the end result would not be suitable for you again.

```
public xAxis_FormatLabel(item: any) {
    return item.Country + " \n" + "some other string";
  }
```

Live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-exckfz-bsvpqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata-chart-type-stacked-column-series%2Fdata-chart-type-stacked-column-series.component.ts

[Here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/data-chart-axis-settings#axis-labels) you can find all the settings related to the Axis